# How to access terminal on chromebook when crosh is blocked

Tags: terminal, chromebook, crosh

Crosh is blocked on my chromebook and I can't find a different terminal. I tried google for the answer and went down a bunch of rabbit holes, and basically everything told me to use crosh, which is blocked. Is there a different terminal that works on chromebook?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an awesome place to ask questions about chromebook for stackexchange, maybe re-ask it on superuser? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176392/where-do-questions-about-customizing-chrome-os-into-a-development-machine-belong

Comment: If you just want to use terminal to ssh to some other server, maybe a chrome app instead? ex: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-app/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en and mosh has a webapp as well.  GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `Setting -> Advanced -> Developers -> Linux development environment` and enable linux that will install linux shell on your chromebook and you will get access to linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that Crosh is the only terminal available, so if your Chromebook is managed by an organization and they blocked it, there is no workaround or any additional terminal that can be used.